# In Drupal 7, where is the code for the "powered by Drupal" block?

Tags: 7, blocks

The "powered by Drupal" block used to be a module in Drupal 6.  I can not find this module in Drupal 7.  Where do I find this module/block? So I can duplicate it, or modify it.

Answer (score 6):

The contents is provided by [`theme_system_powered_by()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/theme_system_powered_by/7), which is turned into a block by [`system_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_block_info/7) and [`system_block_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_block_view/7).

Answer (score -2):

The block itself is located in admin/structure/block, where you can disable for the footer if you'd like.

I would say if you want to duplicate/modify it then you can just create a new block with whatever content you'd like